# I am getting error while executing java program using jdbc

Tags: jdbc

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWnOV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GeIv.png)

Comment: Can you post the sample code that gives you this error. Or you can check the ORA-12505 error

Comment: Check whether the Oracle database is running.check in the services. Do you have the Oracle jar in your project

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061799/listener-refused-the-connection-with-the-following-error-ora-12505-tnslistene

Comment: oracle service is running

Comment: https://mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: Try starting the oraclexclr agent and check